# Invalid Identity Server Tokens

Tags: java, c#, oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver4

I have created a system with 4 main applications:

- the identity server (C#)
- the web app (angular, TS, JS)
- the server side application (Java)
- the API (C#)

The web app authenticates fine, the tokens work like a treat and allow access to the API, but the server-side app doesn't. The tokens seem to be generated correctly but when they are added to the request headers and dispatched they just return a 401 error.

If I generate the token through postman they work correctly but when I generate them through the java application they don't work. Also, they seem to be a different length.

The java application uses the client credentials flow to get token and is implemented like this:

```java
String strBody;
try {
    strBody = "client_id=" + id + "&client_secret=" + URLEncoder.encode(secret, "UTF-8") + "&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + scope;
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Logger.severe("Failed to get encode client secret with error: " + e.getMessage());
    ((CompletableFuture)accessToken).completeExceptionally(new Exception("Failed to get encode client secret with error: " + e.getMessage()));
    return null;
}
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"), strBody);
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
String strResponse = executeRequest(request);
Logger.info("got token response: "+strResponse);
TokenResponse response = (new Gson()).fromJson(strResponse, TokenResponse.class);
if (response.getError() != null && response.getError().length() > 0) {
    Logger.severe("Failed to get access token with error: " + response.getError());
    ((CompletableFuture)accessToken).completeExceptionally(new Exception("Failed to get access token with error: " + response.getError()));
} else {
    Timers.runIn((timer, thing) -> clientCreditentalFlow(), response.getExpiresIn() - 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Logger.info("token: "+accessToken);
    ((CompletableFuture)accessToken).complete(response.getAccessToken());
}
```

When I send the exact same details from post man, it returns a working token, although of a different length.

The web application uses the implicit work flow as opposes to the java app that uses the client credentials flow.

Comment: You would have to provide more details about how the token is requested, and I'd start by comparing the Angular and Java client code.

Comment: I have added some details, please tell me if it's not enough

Comment: make sure you don't have configured "AccessTokenType" in client config to reference and your api is expecting JWT.

Comment: just checked, I don't have it set at all